# Windows wont give internet access to most application

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection

my current problem is that just overnight, without doing anything special or changing or experimenting stuff, I could not access my Internet through windows.
At first, I thought like normal that my internet was gone and just needed to replug/restart the router or wait it out but after waiting I noticed I still received Telegram messages and I could also connect to servers with Teamspeak but my Browser, Email, Discord and Steam did not get any Internet access. Windows said I had no connection, but sometimes it also said I had a connection (in terms of that icon).
So after struggling, I switched to Linux to see if it's just my some weird Server connection problem - I had no problems on Linux, everything was stable.

Alas, Windows still did not work overnight like when the problem just appeared.

Comment: Run TCP/IP Reset and restart the computer. Test.   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer

Comment: It sadly did not work, but I found out that tethering still works

Comment: Perhaps at this point, do a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.